# PDO: Select field from DB which contains a backslash

Tags: mysql, pdo, mariadb

I have table with this conent

```
ID|name
----------------
1 |My Shop No. \6\
```

(Don't ask why the six is within the backslashes, I have no idea, I just have to work with it)

I try to select this specifc value from my table.
My query looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM shops WHERE `name` = :name";
$params = array(':name' => "My Shop No. \6\");
$this->fetchOne($sql, $params); // the binding happens in my mysql class
```

This query does not return any data, it's stating that there is no entry.
When I monitor my SQL statements with the `Neor Profiler SQL`, I can see that the database is receiving this query:

```
SELECT `id` FROM shops WHERE `name` = 'My Shop No. \\6\\'
```

When I use this query directly in PHPMyAdmin, it also does not return any results.

How can I deal with this kind of case?

There is absolutly no option to change the data in the database.

Comment: Backslash has a meaning in PHP strings too. Try `var_dump($params)` to see what I mean. If fact you get it right in SQL and the syntax is the same.

Comment: Okay, the problem is that I struggled to create an example case. The string value is actually coming from an URL parameter. Do you think that this is still a problem then? I also tried to replace the backslashes with double backslashes before passing them to the query. But that did not help at all.

Comment: I made a var_dump. The output is the string as it was received via the url

Comment: String literals are an entirely different thing. Trust `var_dump()`. If a single slash in the URL gets doubled at `var_dump($_GET)` you have a different problem.

Comment: It does not get doubled in the var_dump. It's only doubled within the `Neor Profiler` / MySQL. Until then, the string has only one backslash

Comment: Then I would not discard that it's a cosmetic issue in Neor Profiler display logic and you aren't finding rows because there aren't matches (actual value has trailing whitespace or something like that). What do you get if you run `SELECT id, name, hex(name) FROM shops WHERE name LIKE '%6%'` right in a MariaDB client?

Answer (score 0):

*Many* products (PHP, MySQL, etc) use backslash as the escape character.

By itself, it is *usually* consumed by doing something to the character after it.  For example, `a\tb` gives you the letters `a` and `b` separated by a tab (the *usual* interpretation of `\t`).

Doubling up the backslash `\\xyz` *usually* is intepreted thus:  The first backslash escapes the second, so you get `\xyz`.

If your string goes through multiple layers of code (eg, PDO plus MySQL), you *might* need twice as many backslashes, since each layer will turn `\\` into `\`.

Another diagnostic tool is `SELECT HEX(col) ...` to see what was stored in the database.  Examples:

```
610962    a\tb  -- a=61, tab=09, b=62
615C7462  a\\tb -- a=61, \=5C, t=74, b=62
```

Back to your code:

```
$params = array(':name' => "My Shop No. \6\");

\6 is probably treated as just "6" (not everything has some escaped meaning)
\" possibly caused a syntax error.  Normally this is now to get a " inside a string

'My Shop No. \\6\\'
```

Now the pairs of backslashes are turned into single backslashes, then the string is handed to whoever is next.

(In *these* contexts, single- and double-quotes work the same.)